# import './style.css'; and SyntaxError: Unexpected string when setting up three.js & node.js on live server

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, three.js

Im struggling to get a simple three.js website running on a live server (a2 shared hosting). Ive installed node.js. The start up file is main.js but it doesn't seem to be able to read it.
Im completely new to working with Node. When I start the server I get this error.  Im totally lost...

```
/home/blockc17/app/main.js:1
import './style.css';
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected string
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at Module.require (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper- 
    scripts/node-loader.js:80:25)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at loadApplication (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper- 
    scripts/node-loader.js:243:2)
    at setupEnvironment (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper- 
    scripts/node-loader.js:214:2)


**Main.js imports**

 import './style.css';
 import * as THREE from 'three';
 import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';

// Setup

**package.json**

{
  "name": "blockcb",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "vite": "^2.8.0"
  }
}



**Index.html HEAD**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="favicon.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script type="module" src="./src/main.js"></script>
    <title>BlockChain Bullies</title>
  </head>
```

Forgive me for dumping so much code.  Im not sure of the best way to even approach this issue. Can anyone give me guidance on how to get this app running?

```
[file structure in Cpanel][1]


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYiX7.png
```

Comment: Well, `import './style.css';` is invalid JS. It is valid TypeScript though. If you just want to include the CSS file in the page, just do it normally in HTML: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>`.

Comment: Thank you. Ive included the <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/> in the Index.html.  But the /home/blockc17/app/main.js:1
import './style.css'; error remains. I tried commenting out the ./style.css in main.js but the error moves to the next line.

Comment: _“but the error moves to the next line”_ — Good! You’ve eliminated that error. On to the next one! Honestly, I’d advise you to read the documentation again; it really sounds as if you’re missing a compilation or transpilation step.

Comment: I think the error moves because the previous ./style.css was essentially deleted. It does the same thing when I comment out "import * as THREE from 'three';".  I really do have to go through the documentation. I have very little experience hosting node.js. Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

you need use vite to process the css import.
just run

```
yarn dev
```

Comment: thank you Im getting "yarn run v1.22.17
$ vite
/bin/sh: vite: command not found
error Command failed with exit code 127." Error I will look up this error.